# How to update a table with sum of values from the table itself and another table in MySQL with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are similar questions to this, but the answers are not quite what I have been looking for. I have two MySQL tables, I'll say **table1** and **table2**. The fields in **table1** are *StudentID* , *Grade* and *Total_Score*. And the fields in **table2** are *StudentID* ,*Grade* and *Total_Score* as well. What I want to do is SUM(table1.Total_Score) and add it to SUM(table2.Total_Score). So that *Total_Score* in **table2** is accumulated with scores from **table1**.*Total_Score*.
I have tried to achieve that with my code below but the scores in **table2**.*Total_Score* never accumulate. They stay the same, even though my code gave no error. See my code below.

```
update table2 o inner join
(
SELECT op.StudentID,
sum(ot.Total_Score) as Total_Score_ot
 sum(op.Total_Score) as Total_Score_op
FROM table1 ot inner join table2 op on op.StudentID = ot.StudentID
WHERE ot.Grade = 'Grade8'
GROUP BY op.StudentID
) as o1 on o.StudentID = o1.StudentID
SET Total_Score=Total_Score_op + Total_Score_ot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I don't think you need a join in the subquery:

```
update table2 o inner join
       (select ot.StudentID, sum(ot.Total_Score) as Total_Score_ot
        from table1 ot
        where ot.Grade = 'Grade8'
        group by ot.StudentId
       ) ot
       using (studentid)
    set o.Total_Score = o.Total_Score + Total_Score_ot;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. I tried inserting your code and it gave a syntax error near the line that says using (StudentID). Here is the exact error message - " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(StudentID) SET o.Total_Score = o.Total_Score + Total_Score_ot

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. I took care of the MySQL syntax error. Your answer is ok.